# como limitar la cantidad de updates a una tabla?

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, Busco Ayuda acerca de como podria limitar un update, en el cual quiero que al momento que haya 10 registros de entrada "activos" y que no tengan salida ya no deje hacer mas updates. y a la vez que tome en cuenta los que ya salieron para en que en el conteo de los activos no afecte.

Muchas Gracias

```
     <?php
    error_reporting (0);

    los datos de la conexion funcionan no los puse por seguridad disculpen

    if (!$databaseConn)
    {
    exit ("Error al Intentar conectarse al servidor SQL.");
    }

    $uidVis = $_REQUEST["vis_uid"];


    $updatevis = "UPDATE  visitantes   SET  vis_entrada = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE vis_uid = '".$uidVis."' && vis_entrada = NULL "

    $resultado = mysqli_query($databaseConn ,$updatevis );

    $num = mysqli_affected_rows($databaseConn );

    if($num >0)
    {
    echo "su registro se ha completado, Gracias !";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error,su registro no se ha completado.";
    }
    mysqli_close($databaseConn);
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un procedimiento? un trigger? una consulta antes del update? probaste algun metodo?

Comment: si intente una consulta, pero no se como implementarla en php, ademas soy nuevo en esto olvide mencionarlo.gracias

Comment: podes mostrar lo que implementaste? asi partimos en base a eso...

Comment: Haz un select count(*) y si es más de 10 no hagas el update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No termino de comprender tu escenario, pero creo que hacer una consultar y condicionar tu código en base a ésta puede serte de ayuda.

```
<?php
$uidVis = $_REQUEST["vis_uid"];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM visitantes WHERE vis_entrada = NULL AND vis_salida = NULL";
$result = mysqli_query($databaseConn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

if ($row[0] < 10) {
    $updatevis = "UPDATE visitantes SET vis_entrada = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE vis_uid = '".$uidVis."' && vis_entrada = NULL";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($databaseConn, $updatevis);
    $num = mysqli_affected_rows($databaseConn);

    if ($num > 0) {
        echo "su registro se ha completado, Gracias !";
    } else {
        echo "Error, su registro no se ha completado.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error, su registro no se ha completado porque ya hay por lo menos 10 personas.";
}
mysqli_close($databaseConn);
```